# Getting Object in PHP by key value

Tags: php

I have a very large object that I have to loop through to get a specific object.
I tried `foreach($obj as $item)`, `foreach($obj as $item => $value)` and `for` in various configurations.

**I want to get all the objects where the class is "table-responsive"**

My Element looks like this (in JSON):

```
{
    "dummy":"dummytext",
    "children": [
        {
            "tag":null
        },
        {
            "tag":"body",
            "children": [
                {
                    "class":"not_the_one"
                },
                {
                    "class":"table-responsive",
                    "html":"Gotcha!"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to get as a result is:

```
{
    "class":"table-responsive",
    "html":"Gotcha!"
}
```

There could be more than one object that has the class of "table-responsive", so if there are multiple ones:

```
[
    {
        "class":"table-responsive",
        "html":"Gotcha!"
    },
    {
        "class":"table-responsive",
        "html":"Gotcha!"
    }
]
```

I was trying to accomplish a function that goes through all the elements and checks where the key of class equals "table-responsive" if so, push the object to an array. (`array_push($result, $obj);`) If the current element is an array, loop through it too. There can be a lot of dimensions so ideally the function calls itself. (recursive)

Comment: "I was trying to accomplish a function" then you should show that to us :) Your approach is good, so where exactly do you have problem?

Comment: If one of your `table-responsive` classed objects has `children`, should they be kept in the result? What properties from the _found_ objects should be present in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is a recursive *reduce* operation. Something that can

1. Iterate your elements
2. Capture any with the matching property, and
3. Perform the same operation on any `children`

```php
// decode your JSON into an associative array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// setup search parameters
$findKey = 'class';
$findValue = 'table-responsive';

// create a recursive reducer
$reducer = function($carry, $item) use (&$reducer, $findKey, $findValue) {
    if (array_key_exists($findKey, $item) && $item[$findKey] === $findValue) {
        // if this $item matches, add it to the $carry array
        $carry[] = $item;
    }
    if (!empty($item['children'])) {
        // this $item has children so dive deeper
        return array_reduce($item['children'], $reducer, $carry);
    }
    // no children in this one so on to the next iteration
    return $carry;
};

// Run the reducer at the top level. 
// Note I've wrapped the root object in an array so the reducer can iterate it
$found = array_reduce([ $data ], $reducer, []);

// and display
echo json_encode($found, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/6mWmC

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil. I'm gonna test ist tomorrow, seems like the right thing. And thanks for the interactive example. I really appreciate your help. It's the first time posting here so I'm happy to get such a good answer. I'll try to look out for things that I can help with too on here. Stay safe and have a nice day ;-)